# Where do offline synced google docs get stored on Mac OS X?

Tags: google-chrome, google-docs

If I turn on google docs/sheets/drive offline sync through chrome on os x and activate "Make Available Offline" for some doc, where is the doc stored locally on my machine?

I am not talking about google back up and sync - I am talking specifically about activating offline docs sync through a browser (in this case chrome).

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12797114/google-drive-offline-document-file-location) gives the answer for PC, Android, and Linux but not mac. I looked in all the typical Application Support folders as well as in Chrome Developer Tools --> Sources --> Filesystem and also Developer Tools --> Application --> IndexedDB but I cannot figure it out. IndexedDB --> GoogleDriveDs --> Offline shows an entry for offline synced files (and not others) but it doesn't help me find it locally on my disk.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is stored in:

~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/IndexedDB

where "Default" might need to be substituted by your profile name.